# Autostart Cygwin on Windows boot and run a cygwin command

Tags: windows, cygwin, batch

Sometimes my Windows server reboots at night to install new updates. Then the next day I find out that my cygwin instance has been stopped.

What I want is on Windows start, also run Cygwin AND run a specific command.

so, step 1:
Right now I have a cygwin.bat to start cygwin:

```
@echo off
C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin
bash --login -i
```

step 2 is to enter the command in the command windows that appears after running cygwin.bat:

```
cd /cygdrive/e/solr/apache-solr-4.0-2010-10-12_08-05-48/example/;java -Dsolr.solr.home="./example-DIH/solr/" -jar start.jar
```

But this command is what I want to have called automatically when i run cygwin.bat

How can I combine step 1 and step 2 into a single bat file which I can run on Windows start?

Comment: How goes the battle, Peter?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new .bat file that runs on startup, and use the `bash -c` option to pass commands to bash when you start it. For example:

```
@echo off
C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin
bash -c "echo 'it works'; read -n 1 -p 'Press any key to continue...' "
```

You could also make the changes to your cygwin.bat, but then the commands would run every time you start a shell.

Answer (score 1):

I try to keep my windows experience as UNIX like as possible.  The first thing I would reach for would be installing cron and using @REBOOT to run a script on startup.

I found a good writeup on installing cron here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7900158/1607020

Then, make a file in /etc/cron.d/myservicename with

```
@REBOOT /path/to/bash/script > /tmp/myservicename.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

I now have this:

```
@echo off

C:

chdir C:\cygwin\bin

bash -c cd /cygdrive/e/solr/apache-solr-4.0-2010-10-12_08-05-48/example/;java -Dsolr.solr.home="./example-DIH/solr/" -jar start.jar

bash -c "echo 'it works'; read -n 1 -p 'Press any key to continue...' "
```

But that doesnt seem to start cygwin with the commands I want to...

Comment: You should have appended this to your question, not add a "pseudoanswer" with another version of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method:

1. On Windows 7, open Task Scheduler (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler)
2. On the right "Create Task..."
3. On "Actions" in "Program/script": <letter>:\<path_to_cygwin>\bin\bash.exe (I have `D:\Apps\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe`)
4. On "Add arguments (optional)": -c "<anything you want to execute inside bash>" (I have `-c "sleep 60; while true; do /cygdrive/d/xampp/scripts/daily_work_no_wait.sh >> /cygdrive/d/xampp/monitor/daily_work_no_wait.out.txt ; done"` with quotes)